# How to download the Android dungeons in-app billing example?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am reading the Android page about in-app billing and they have a sample program discussed here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

but I don't see how to download it.  They have a number of links to download which all go to the top of the download section.

Any idea how to actually download that sample app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

As nmr pointed in his comment the current(new) folder for the sample is:

**< sdk >/extra/play_billing/market_billing_r02.zip**

Read carefully:

> The in-app billing sample application is available as a downloadable
>   component of the Android SDK. To download the sample application
>   component, launch the Android SDK Manager and then select the Google
>   Market Billing package component (see figure 1), and click Install
>   Selected to begin the download.

So use the `Android SDK Manager` to download it(look at the bottom of the list(the `Extras` folder)). After you install that package you can find the sample project in:

```
<sdk>/extras/google/market_billing/
```

< sdk > is where you installed the `android SDK`.

Comment: Most Android sample apps can be installed using New -> Android Sample Product. Dungeons is actually an Extra, so it must be loaded direct form the file system. For some of us the example app is not in the "google" folder. It was mislabeled with an inconsistent hyphen/underscore name: <sdk>/extras/google-market_billing/

Comment: As of today I don't see the v2 sample in that directory any more. I had some trouble finding it at first, but I see that it's now in `<sdk>/extra/play_billing/market_billing_r02.zip`.

Comment: @nmr You are right, my answer was bound to become invalid at some point in the future. I've edited my answer to include the new path. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The in-app billing sample application is available as a downloadable component of the Android SDK. To download the sample application component, launch the Android SDK Manager and then select the Google Market Billing package component (see figure 1), and click Install Selected to begin the download.
[image]

When the download is complete, the Android SDK Manager saves the component into the following directory:

```
<sdk>/extras/google/market_billing/
```